# Retaining UICollectionViewCell while scrolling a UICollectionView

Tags: objective-c, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to figure out a way to keep a UICollectionViewCell from being removed (didEndDisplayingCell) from my UICollectionView when its original scroll position scrolls off of the view. I know this is the way a UICollectionView is supposed to work, that cells are removed and returned to the reuse pool when they are no longer visible, but this is based on their original position in the UICollectionView. I'm trying to drag that cell past the original visible area into a further away location, but it gets removed killing the pan gesture in progress and killing its view in the collection view once its original position is scrolled out of view. Is there a way to override this behavior and hold onto a UICollectionViewCell until I'm done with it?

I've seen the other ways to attack this problem by creating an image of the cell and dragging that instead, but that won't satisfy my purposes. I need the original cell to survive beyond its original screen position as I scroll through the UICollectionView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make copy when dragging your cell around and hide original cell.

Comment: Duping the cell turns out to be somewhat complicated, only because I have to return the subviews for the duped cell back to the original once the cell is permanently moved to its new location. The cell is displaying live updates that I want to continue while I move it around, and when it arrives at its new location. Any suggestions as to how one might best accomplish this?

Comment: You can create your cell with simple `initWithFrame:`, in the end it's just an UIView, provide frame manually because the cell is not handled by collection view anymore but rather by your controller. You can copy frame from original cell. and certainly when cell arrives to final position, you can animate changes in collection view by removing original cell and inserting the new one.

Comment: I don't see the reason why you would mess with subviews. Because you could simply set data from model on both new and drag cells.